# Getting undefined error while setting a state

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using API to extract data from Amazon API and I am using react js for it.

The problem is when I extract them and save it in the state it gives me an error of undefined, however, I am getting the result from the API. The function takes time to get data from API, I am using a method of extracting data which is suitable in node js but also working in react and I am getting a result, but unable to save it in a state. Here's the code below:

```
    let getReport={
        path:'/',
        query:{
            Action:'GetReport',
            ReportId:'14941942615018036',
            Version:'2009-01-01',
        }
    };

    let temp=null;

    mws.request(getReport, function(e, result) {
        temp=result;
        this.setState({amazon_data:result})  // gives undefined error
    });
```

I think the reason is the function execution takes time and it runs the setstate line which makes the result null, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Show result content by `console.log(result)`

Comment: The content is shown but I want it to save in a state, when I do it gives me undefined error.

Comment: is `this` undefined? Also, did you previously initialize it with `this.state = {...}` ?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined , I am receiving this error

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio yes I have initialized state in a constructor

Comment: please try to  `console.log(this)` right before `temp=results;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because `this.setState` is not part of the `this` scope inside your function.

```
 let getReport={
        path:'/',
        query:{
            Action:'GetReport',
            ReportId:'14941942615018036',
            Version:'2009-01-01',
        }
    };

    let temp=null;
    const _this = this;
    mws.request(getReport, function(e, result) {
        temp=result;
        _this.setState({amazon_data:result})  // this works because _this references the outer this
    });
```

That should work or you can use arrow functions like below.

```
 let getReport={
        path:'/',
        query:{
            Action:'GetReport',
            ReportId:'14941942615018036',
            Version:'2009-01-01',
        }
    };

    let temp=null;

    mws.request(getReport, (e, result) => {
        temp=result;
        this.setState({amazon_data:result})  // this works because the arrow function binds the outer this to the function
    });
```